# Freshly installed JBoss 4.2.3.GA has no admin-console?

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I clean-installed JBoss 4.2.3.GA and ran it via Eclipse.

I can see verify it's running via a web browser:

[image]

While its web console seems to be empty:

[image]

So, I tried accessing http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin-console instead, as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702118/8080472). But all I am getting is "The requested resource (/admin-console) is not available":

[image]

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

How do I get either the web console or the admin-console to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `http://fully-qualified.hostname:8080/admin-console` in JBoss 4.2.3GA.

But there is the `http://fully-qualified.hostname:8080/web-console` Java application.

The reason it is empty is because starting with `Java 7 Update 51`, Java does not allow users to run applications that are not signed, self-signed or that are missing permission attributes.

To workaround this, add your server's URL to the [Exception Site List](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml). **Note:** you may need to `Run as administrator` the `Configure Java` applet.

Once you save the revised exception site list, web-console's JBoss Management Console will be revealed:

[image]